# WCF rest hosting on IIS

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, hosting

I have an wcf rest service. I hosted it in IIS with following service configuration

```html
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="CRM_Service.CRM_Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
         binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_ICRM_Service" contract="CRM_Service.ICRM_Service" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="*********" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding_ICRM_Service" closeTimeout="00:04:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500"
            maxConcurrentInstances="500" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
       logMalformedMessages="true"
       maxMessagesToLog="5000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

I used separate application pool for this project. After hosting it worked fine for some duration,but after that service was not responding for any method call. Please help me to come out this issue. Thanks in advance...

Comment: what error happens when you open your service address in a browser? you can also enable tracing to help you detect the problem, see more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. There is no any error occurred while execution of service method call, actually service calling end not getting any response after few  successful calls.Even I tried to give call from browser also, but result was same, just processing request , not any successful execution.

Comment: Even though there's no error enabling trace will help getting the footprint of method calls. Analyse it carefully and see what's has happened before the service goes in not responding state.